# how to do automated testing on forms using captcha?

Tags: automated-tests, captcha

how to do automated testing on forms using captcha ? I am using selenium to create tests ..I got to go past a captcha test and verify the next page that comes.......

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a way to induce a known captcha onto the page.  Then you can simply fill in the fields as required and submit the form.  If you can do it with an arbitrary captcha, your captcha's not going to do you much good.

Comment: That the simplest solution, i too thought the ditto, but then i am not able to figure out how to do that? Do Captcha does not have any interface to tweak that.

Answer (score 1):

Either have a known captcha on the page, as tvanfosson suggests, or a configuration setting to turn off the captcha validation for your test environment.

Answer (score 0):

I used message popup which will be displayed until pressed ok and our execution will be paused so that manually we can enter captcha code.
It will be better approach than `Thread.sleep();`

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try a free trial of Automation Anywhere. I think you could create a task and see how it goes.

http://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/automatedtesting.htm